# Android Custom View Not Drawing Line B/W Points

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout, custom-view

Below is the custom view thats used to have a single point on the screen
i want to draw a line between two Points
basically its a app known as Auto Clicker
now for single points its as well as it could be
i want to add a gesture func in it
the functionilty for gesture is also going well but i only want to update the view
The PointView class is as follows:

````
class PointView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    val pointConfig: PointConfig = PointConfig(0, 0, 200)
) : LifecycleView(context, attrs) {
    var pointBinding: PointBinding
    var number = MutableLiveData(0)
    var params = MutableLiveData<WindowManager.LayoutParams>()
    var pointConfigPopupWindow: PopupWindow? = null
    private var xInView = 0.0f
    private var yInView = 0.0f
    private var xInScreen = 0.0f
    private var yInScreen = 0.0f
    private val windowManager by lazy { context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager }
    private val linePaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = android.graphics.Color.WHITE
        strokeWidth = 5f
    }
    init {
        pointBinding = PointBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
        number.observe(this) {
            pointBinding.tvPoint.text = it.toString()
        }
        params.observe(this) {
            pointConfig.x = it.x
            pointConfig.y = it.y
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(this, it)
        }
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        LogUtils.d("x: ${event?.x},y: ${event?.y},rawX: ${event?.rawX},rawY: ${event?.rawY}, event: $event")
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                xInView = event.x
                yInView = event.y
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                xInScreen = event.rawX
                yInScreen = event.rawY
                if (ScreenUtils.isPortrait()) {
                    yInScreen -= ScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight()
                } else {
                    xInScreen -= ScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight()
                }
                updateViewPosition()
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                if (event.x == xInView && event.y == yInView) {
                    // Clicked
                    LogUtils.d("Point clicked.")
//                    MyWindowManager.showPointConfigPopupWindow(this)
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun updateViewPosition() {
        params.value?.x = (xInScreen - xInView).toInt()
        params.value?.y = (yInScreen - yInView).toInt()
        updateViewLayout()
        LogUtils.d("x: ${params.value?.x}, y: ${params.value?.y}")
    }
    fun drawLineTo(endPoint: PointView) {
        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(x + width / 2, y + height / 2)
        path.lineTo(endPoint.x + endPoint.width / 2, endPoint.y + endPoint.height / 2)
        val canvas = Canvas()
        canvas.drawPath(path, linePaint)
        (this as View).invalidate()
    }
    fun updateViewLayout() {
        params.postValue(params.value)
    }

    fun centerPoint(): Point {
        return Point(
            params.value!!.x + width / 2,
            params.value!!.y + ScreenUtils.getStatusBarHeight() + height / 2
        )
    }

    fun bright() {
        pointBinding.tvPoint.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marrowfocused)
        pointBinding.tvPoint.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.black))
    }

    fun dark() {
        pointBinding.tvPoint.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marrow)
        pointBinding.tvPoint.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.black))
    }
}```
and the class its being extending is as follows
````

open class LifecycleView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs),
LifecycleOwner {

```
private val lifecycleRegistry by lazy { LifecycleRegistry(this) }

override val lifecycle: Lifecycle
    get() = lifecycleRegistry

override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.CREATED
}

override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
}

override fun onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility: Int) {
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility)
    if (visibility == VISIBLE) {
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    } else if (visibility == GONE || visibility == INVISIBLE) {
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    }
}
```

}

```
the way i'm calling it as follows
private fun drawLineBetweenPoints(startPoint: PointView, endPoint: PointView) {
        startPoint.drawLineTo(endPoint)
    }
```

```
i tried manipulating the drawLine fun as much as i could but didnt get that
one solution can be that i can make a new view for the gesture and check if gesture then infalte that but all i want is to make chagnes in this so that i could get rid of that headache
```